# URI Update Request

Tags: c#

From my C# console application, I want to issue an Uri update request. Like the following:

```
http://username:password@dynupdate.no-ip.com/nic/update?hostname=mytest.testdomain.com&myip=1.2.3.4
```

I have tried the following:

```
string url = "http://username:password@dynupdate.no-ip.com/nic/update? hostname=mytest.testdomain.com&myip=1.2.3.4";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Timeout = 5000;
```

But, I am getting, `Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.` error.

Any idea, where I went wrong? I type the full url as shown above into a web browser and it works as expected but through the C# application, it throws an exception.

Is there any other way to implement this?

Comment: Can you try by encoding the URL  Something like this http://username:password@dynupdate.no-ip.com/nic/update?%20hostname%3Dmytest.testdomain.com%26myip%3D1.2.3.4

Comment: @VamsiMohanJayanti I have tested that but it will throw the, "The URI prefix is not recognized" exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create and add some credentials to the request and then access the URI without passing in the username/password.

For more information : [How to: Request Data Using the WebRequest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f.aspx) (Specifically the section regarding credentials)

For example;

```
var uri = new Uri("http://somesite.com/something");
var request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myUserName","myPassword");
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
```

Comment: Yes, I have looked into this but not sure of the implementation. For e.g. in my case the uri is "http://username:password@dynupdate.no-ip.com/nic/update? hostname=mytest.testdomain.com&myip=1.2.3.4". How do I ensure that the username and password will be set to the front of the uri?

Comment: Managed to do it. It will be assigned automatically. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Just have look at this web page. Is this what you are referring to?
http://www.no-ip.com/integrate/request/

I think you need to use the url as 
http://dynupdate.no-ip.com/nic/update

and then send the credentials as mentioned by ChrisBint. And you need to set the preference to base64 ...if there is a provision for that 
+ some headers like UserAgent as mentioned in the article.

Answer (score 0):

```
Encode the URL argument, check the below example

string url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com?question=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("a sentence with spaces");

WebRequest r = WebRequest.Create(url);
```